# PHP: How to secure a 'plaintext' password within a PHP file in .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, nginx, phpmailer

I have a nginx server that redirects traffic to a folder (lets just call the folder 'htaccess', for example) to a 404 page so that I can store a plaintext password inside of a php file. The thing is that, this feels extremely insecure but it is needed to access my mysql database.

Found on a guide online:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'redacted');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'redacted');
define('DB_NAME', 'redacted');
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Similarly, I needed to store my password for a SMTP server using PHPMailer and my solution was to make a .php file with the variables $password and $username and include this file (located in the htaccess folder) in order to connect to the server. However, this also feels insecure but I am unable to find a way around this. My main concern is that a user can simply inject php code and do `echo $password` and reveal the variable that the php file is referencing. Can anyone point me the right direction? Is .htaccess a secure way of hiding data on your server?

htaccess/user-config.php:

```
$pass='somepassword';
$user='someuser';
```

php file outside of htaccess:

```
// for examples sake, I'll call the folder 'htaccess'
include htaccess/user-config.php

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Username = $user;
$mail->Password = $pass;
```

Comment: The usual recommendation is to store such files holding credentials above the domain root. _“My main concern is that a user can simply inject php code and do echo $password and reveal the variable that the php file is referencing.”_ - there’s little can be done about that at this point. If people can execute their own arbitrary PHP code in your system, it is too late already in most regards.

Comment: But would storing it in an htaccess folder be a security issue? I mean, the user shouldn't be able to access, or have knowledge of the folder and the files within. Is this accurate, or am I not taking something else into consideration?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

The right way to avoid needing to use htaccess is to put such config files outside the web root. This is why most frameworks have their web root pointed at a `public` folder which contains static assets (images, CSS) and an index.php that loads files from `../`, something like:

```
- app
  - controllers
  - models
  - views
  - public    <-- web root
    - img
    - css
    index.php <-- app entry point
  config.php  <-- config outside web root
```

This solves one problem, but leaves open the other issue you mention - exposing system config variables. The most common way of leaking this info is by leaving debug settings enabled, where stack traces and verbose error messages can reveal a lot - so make sure you only ever show generic error messages on production systems, and make staging or test environments inaccessible to unauthorised users. The concern you expressed about being able to "simply inject" user-supplied PHP is indeed a problem, but that would represent a very major remote code execution (RCE) vulnerability bug in your app, and leakage of credentials would be the least of your worries. This is why most frameworks structure things so as to avoid that kind of problem.

One minor advantage of using a `.php` file for storing config info is that if it is accessed directly, it will run the PHP (which does nothing and produces no output) rather than showing the contents of the file. This is not true of .ini, JSON or yaml files.

One way to avoid having the config in a file at all is to pass it through environment variables, however, these values still end up appearing in the PHP runtime environment (most obviously in `$_ENV`, but elsewhere too).

Ultimately it's like being worried about someone getting into your house if you give them your keys; the solution is not to give them the keys.